# How would you access a specific cell of a dynamically generated table?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a table that is generated dynamically:

```
{% for r in result %}
<tr>
        <td>
            <form action="/deleteBook" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" id="deleteBtn" value="Delete"/>
           </form> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="/editBook" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" id="editBtn" value="Edit"/>
           </form> 
        </td>
        <td id="itemID">{{r.itemID}}</td>
        <td> {{r.title}}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to access the itemID of the row where the respective form submit button was pressed. I know the way I have it set up, every single row will have a column with an id "itemID", I just want to know if it's possible to easily reference the rows even if they don't have unique ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler receives an Event object, which has two properties:

- `target`, which is the element that clicked
- `currentTarget`, which is the element you hooked the event on (which may be an ancestor of `target`)

I'd probably use event delegation here, hooking `click` on the `table` or `tbody`, so `currentTarget` would be the table not not particularly helpful, but `target` will be the button. From the button you can find the row (`tr`), and then within the row you can find the `td` for the item.

I'd get rid of all of those `id`s, though, since `id`s are **required** to be unique on the page. Use class names instead. So:

```
document.getElementById("id-for-the-table").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const item = event.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".itemID");
    // ...use `item` here... For instance, `item.textContent` will be the item ID
});
```

Live Example:

```js
document.getElementById("the-table").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const item = event.target.closest("tr").querySelector(".itemID");
    // ...use `item` here... For instance, `item.textContent` will be the item ID
    console.log("Item ID: " + item.textContent);
});
// Just for the example, I prevent forms being submitted
document.getElementById("the-table").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<table id="the-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="/deleteBook" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete"/>
                   </form> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/editBook" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="editBtn" value="Edit"/>
                   </form> 
                </td>
                <td class="itemID">1</td>
                <td> Title 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="/deleteBook" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete"/>
                   </form> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/editBook" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="editBtn" value="Edit"/>
                   </form> 
                </td>
                <td class="itemID">2</td>
                <td> Title 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="/deleteBook" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="deleteBtn" value="Delete"/>
                   </form> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form action="/editBook" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" class="editBtn" value="Edit"/>
                   </form> 
                </td>
                <td class="itemID">3</td>
                <td> Title 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Note that that uses the new(ish) [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method on Element. If you need to support obsolete browsers like IE, you can polyfill it.

Also note that I've used ES2015+ (`const`), but if (again) you need to support obsolete browsers, you can use `var` there instead.